# Looping a Brightcove hosted video

Tags: video, embed, brightcove

I am working with a Brightcove hosted video and I am trying to do two things:

1. Loop the video
2. Change the video "poster," or initial image before the user presses play

I, unfortunately do not have access to anything but the following code:

```
<object id="flashObj" width="480" height="270" 
classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,47,0">
    <param name="movie" value="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
    <param name="flashVars" value="videoId=3492053615001&linkBaseURL=http%3A%2F%2Fh20621.www2.hp.com%2Fvideo-gallery%2Fus%2Fen%2Fproducts%2Fdesktop-and-all-in-one-computers%2Fprofessional%2F3492053615001%2Fhp-eliteone-800-all-in-one-extended-family-demo%2Fvideo%2F&playerID=1111577658001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAABAeI3VIE~,N0OfmZCPaxgxui0PhG4ilXrKUlL_O1tR&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" />
    <param name="base" value="http://admin.brightcove.com" />
    <param name="seamlesstabbing" value="false" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="swLiveConnect" value="true" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <embed src="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1" 
    bgcolor="#FFFFFF" 
    flashVars="videoId=3492053615001&linkBaseURL=http%3A%2F%2Fh20621.www2.hp.com%2Fvideo-gallery%2Fus%2Fen%2Fproducts%2Fdesktop-and-all-in-one-computers%2Fprofessional%2F3492053615001%2Fhp-eliteone-800-all-in-one-extended-family-demo%2Fvideo%2F&playerID=1111577658001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAABAeI3VIE~,N0OfmZCPaxgxui0PhG4ilXrKUlL_O1tR&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" 
    base="http://admin.brightcove.com" 
    name="flashObj" width="1190" height="800" 
    seamlesstabbing="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    allowFullScreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" swLiveConnect="true" 
    pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">
    </embed>
</object>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this without accessing the API.  The point is that if you don't own the player, you shouldn't control how it behaves. You may want to request an API token from the owner so you might have access.  Typical Brightcove accounts allow up to 6.

[Here's the documentation](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/samples/creating-video-loop.html)  to use the API for looping a video.

Comment: Figured as much. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Here's are two super helpful GISTs to accomplish this...

https://gist.github.com/bcls/98670e871cc7a8ef521e

https://gist.github.com/bcls/7457328

...these are from BrightCove.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I have no way to check if this works for my problem anymore, but I upvoted because it seems helpful!